# I have a question about who we should do testing phase in transformers for time series forecasting

Tags: transformer-model

In this article https://medium.com/inside-machine-learning/what-is-a-transformer-d07dd1fbec04 the author used an empty sequence with start of the token as first element for feeding to the decoder in inference phase. For empty sequence I considered a sequence with the start token as first element and zeros as remaining elements. For instance if the output window is in size of 3, I considered a sequence with length of three ( the first element is start of the token and the remaining is zero) then these zero will be replaced with new token generated in each step. It will be continued till our sequence fed to the decoder has been filled with all new tokens. I want to know if I am in a right path? The empty sequence that I considered is a right thing ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have mentioned a link. The problem is completely explained in that link . My problem is about the inference part in that article